# Stored procedure Option

Tags: sql-server-2005

I use sql server 2005 and I want to find stored procedure option but I can not how can I find it please help me thanks

Comment: ??? your question is very unclear - **what** are you trying to find?? What are you trying to do?? Call a stored procedure? Create one?

Answer (score 0):

Click on your Database, expand Programmability.  It is the first option there.

Comment: aha yes I found it thanks also is there any check syntax box in sql server 2005?

Comment: @matin1234: Yes, the is a tick in the SQL Editor toolbar, or you can use Ctrl+F5 to parse your syntax.